# Reduce whitespace after \ref

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, labels, white-space, ref

I have the following latex file:

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
Some text here {\ref{fig:example_graph}}, followed by text here, Table {\ref{tab:lfr_nets}}, and some text here
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{images/Unknown.png}
    \caption{\hl{Example Graph}}
    \label{fig:example_graph}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
\begin{tabu} to 0.8\textwidth {X[l] X[l] X[l] X[l]}
    \hline
    \textbf {A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} &  \textbf{D} \\
    \hline
    LFR1 & 20 & 34 & 1.7\\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\caption{Properties of generated LFR Networks}
    \label{tab:lfr_nets}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This gets rendered like this, with extra space between the 1 and the comma
[image]

[Raw Log](https://pastebin.com/7fTSLE0P)

---

*Addendum*: Here's a hopefully almost fully minimal example. It generates the unwanted extra space after cross-references to objects of type `figure` and `table`, but not to objects of type `section` and `equation`. The version of the `WileyNJD-v2` class is `2017/06/23 v0.2`. The problem behavior is not unique to `\ref`: it surfaces with `\autoref` and `\cref` as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[colorlinks]{WileyNJD-v2}
\listfiles % print a list of all files that get loaded to the log file
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} % for '\Cref' command

\begin{document}
% increment a few counters via \refstepcounter and provide \label instructions
\refstepcounter{section}\label{sec:ex}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:example_graph}
\refstepcounter{table}\label{tab:lfr_nets}
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:triv}

Figure \ref{fig:example_graph}. \autoref{fig:example_graph}. \Cref{fig:example_graph}. 

Table \ref{tab:lfr_nets}. \autoref{tab:lfr_nets}. \Cref{tab:lfr_nets}.
 
Section \ref{sec:ex}. \autoref{sec:ex}. \Cref{sec:ex}.

Equation \eqref{eq:triv}. \autoref{eq:triv}. \Cref{eq:triv}
\end{document}
```

The file list is as follows (the document was compiled with MacTeX2020, all updates applied):

```
WileyNJD-v2.cls    2017/06/23 v0.2 Standard LaTeX document class for Journal
 article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
   fleqn.clo    2016/12/29 v1.2b Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
  size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
multicol.sty    2019/12/09 v1.8y multicolumn formatting (FMi)
multirow.sty    2019/05/31 v2.5 Span multiple rows of a table
   cuted.sty    2012/10/04 v1.5 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
changepage.sty    2009/10/20 v1.0c check page and change page layout
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
floatpag.sty    1999/04/29 FLOAT PAGESTYLE
dblfloatfix.sty    2012/12/31 v1.0a (JAW)
fixltx2e.sty    2016/12/29 v2.1a fixes to LaTeX (obsolete)
rotating.sty    2016/08/11 v2.16d rotated objects in LaTeX
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
longtable.sty    2020/01/07 v4.13 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
    ulem.sty    2019/11/18
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
    soul.sty    2003/11/17 v2.4 letterspacing/underlining (mf)
 caption.sty    2020/01/03 v3.4h Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2020/01/03 v1.8h caption3 kernel (AR)
ltcaption.sty    2020/05/30 v1.4b longtable captions (AR)
hyperref.sty    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend.sty    2019-12-11 v1.11 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
bookmark.sty    2019/12/03 v1.28 PDF bookmarks (HO)
bkm-pdftex.def    2019/12/03 v1.28 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
  twoopt.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Definitions with two optional arguments (HO)
footmisc.sty    2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
tabularx.sty    2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
   array.sty    2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
 dcolumn.sty    2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
showframe.sty    2011/02/24 v0.1i showframe (new impl., RN)
 eso-pic.sty    2018/04/12 v2.0h eso-pic (RN)
booktabs.sty    2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
 amsmath.sty    2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2020/05/29 v2.20.6
algorithm.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environment
algorithmicx.sty    2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx
algpseudocode.sty    
listings.sty    2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2020/03/24 1.8d listings configuration
   alltt.sty    1997/06/16 v2.0g defines alltt environment
 wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
cleveref.sty    2018/03/27 v0.21.4 Intelligent cross-referencing
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-06-23 L3 backend support: PDF mode
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2019/12/03 v1.3 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How or where is the `\hl` macro defined? Which document class do you employ? Do you load any packages that affect the way cross-references are typeset?

Comment: Please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. Witht the information you provided so far, I can not reproduce the output you get.

Comment: "Normally" that should not happen. If I complete the code shown so far to a minimal example document https://gist.github.com/moewew/c91842ffa6bdd03a92625173329f8691 I cannot reproduce the extra space. Please try to minimise (a copy of!) your document to reproduce the excess space with as little code as possible.

Comment: @moewe : didn't know an `mwe` package existed, nice!

Comment: @agryson It comes with a few handy example images (`example-image.(pdf|png|jpg|eps)`). One doesn't actually have to load `\usepackage{mwe}` to use the images, but if one does, the error message is clearer in case the package is not installed (and hence the images not available). Other than that the package just loads `graphicx`,`lipsum` and `blindtext`.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code. `WileyNJD-v2` doesn't appear to be on CTAN. Can you point us to where you got it from, please?

Comment: @moewe There you go. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/pb-assets/assets/25778196/ENGR_LaTeX_template-1547576118397.zip

Comment: How do you compile your document? With pdfLaTeX, LaTeX (to dvi), XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? Consider posting the full `.log` file.

Comment: @moewe I am using pdflatex.

Comment: Thanks for the log. If I use an image I have (see code https://gist.github.com/moewew/36dae9d1c90c644d608334407ca6e310) and compile the document with pdfLaTeX, the links an `\ref` output look fine. Some of your packages are a bit older than mine, but I couldn't see anything spectacular. Do you see the excess space in all PDF viewers or only with some viewers?

Comment: The same as moewe: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @egreg and @moewe - I've posted an MWE -- see above -- that manages to replicate the author's issue for cross-references to `figure` and `table` objects.

Comment: @ParthVerma - I've taken the liberty of appending a nearly-minimal example LaTeX document to your query. The sample document generates extra whitespace after cross-references to objects of type `figure` and `table`.

Comment: @Mico I get no spurious space.

Comment: @egreg - You run MacTeX2020 as well, right?

Comment: @Mico Yes, but for some reason in my file list I get `etex.sty` which is not in yours. Well, the package *is* loaded by the class, so you should get it as well.

Comment: @moewe I see the error in all PDF viewers

Comment: Hrmm, very odd. Mico apparently managed to reproduce your issue and added a shorter example. Even with his new MWE I can't reproduce the problem, though. My `\listfiles` list differs slightly from Mico's in that my document loads `etex.sty`, doesn't load `longtable.sty` and `ltcaption.sty`, has a slightly newer version of `caption.sty` and `caption3.sty` and doesn't load `epstopdf-sys.cfg`. On first glance I would have dismissed these little differences as irrelevant, but now they are the only thing we have. Can you please post your `\listfiles` output for Mico's code example at the end?

Comment: @Mico Did you run the MWE with the version of `WileyNJD-v2` the OP linked? I'm wondering why your system loads `longtable`. In the version of `WileyNJD-v2.cls` that I downloaded from the link the only mention of `longtable` is commented out `%\RequirePackage{longtable}%` (l. 263). The version I downloaded also explicitly calls `\usepackage{etex}%` so it should appear in the `\listfiles` output.

Comment: I downloaded a slightly different version of the class from https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/14678640/homepage/custom_copy.htm. With that version my `\listfiles` output looks almost like @Mico's, there are only two differences: My versions of `caption.sty` and `caption3.sty` are newer (2020/05/30 vs 2020/01/03) and my `\listfiles` doesn't mention `epstopdf-sys.cfg`

Comment: @moewe - Downloading the class file from the site you provided did the trick, i.e, removed the unwanted whitespace after cross-references to `figure` and `table` objectds! I must have had an older version of the class file (confusingly also called `2017/06/23 v0.2`) hanging about in the folder where I do most of my work for TeX.SE. I can only guess that the older file was there because I previously contributed answers on TeX.SE to postings that involved the `WileyNJD-v2` class...

Comment: @Mico so what you are saying is I should use the version from the link provided by moewe ?

Comment: @ParthVerma - Yes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it in the following way:

1. open the file named *WileyNJD-v2.cls*;
2. find the following two strings:

*\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}\enspace }

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}\enspace }*

3. please, delete the *\enspace*
4. enjoy!